# Mask is not working in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Hi all I am trying to blur the edges of an image from one side only, using mask property so that background of body tag blend with image for ex. have a look on below image.

[image]     [image]

i've tried [link](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) by which it is running perfectly on all the browsers but except IE and opera. although I've seen in many blogs masking property doesn't work properly with IE. Please find my code snippet below

```
    <svg  width="503" height="373">
    <defs>
        <filter id="filter">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask">
            <rect y="0" height="400" width="300" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)" ></rect>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="503" height="373" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
    <foreignObject width="503px" height="373px" style="mask: url(#mask);"></foreignObject>
</svg>
```

if I can't do this with masking then please suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i got it, how it could be done for IE. here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5e2zyyt/2/)

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="1" offset="70%" />
          <stop stop-color="#000000" stop-opacity="1" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
        <mask id="mask4" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200">
          <rect style="fill: url(#gradient1); stroke: none;" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <image mask="url(&quot;#mask4&quot;)" width="300" height="200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest editing the photo in Photoshop and using that instead of the masking. That means that the browsers will render the image rather than the CSS. There are many tutorials on the web which will tell you how to edit the photo on Photoshop.

Alternatively, this workaround by [Martin Beeby](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/12/08/i-would-like-to-mask-a-html5-video-element-and-convert-it-into-a-triangle-i-want-a-solution-that-will-work-in-ie9-firefox-and-chrome-is-it-possible.aspx) seemed to work. Looks complicated though!

Good luck...

Comment: That would not be a good solution if there are multiple images to be used or if the images are loaded dynamically. I think the OP is looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore Seeing as `mask` is not supported by IE at all, this is the only solution if the OP wants it to work on IE.

Comment: There are a few options which do work in IE([for eg](http://jsfiddle.net/w4usc5bs/1/)) which might be possible to change and used differently

Comment: @Theo no that's not the right thing to do I don't want to do it in photoshop.as images are dynamic.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore yes, you guessed it right images are coming dynamically although your fiddle is working in IE but it's not very clear.

Comment: @user3584501 Well if you can't use photoshop then use Martin's guide I posted above or Samy's suggestion.